# Calculate DOB in years and days?

Tags: sql-server, date

I am working on Date Of Birth (DOB) requirement. IF user age is more than 16 years and 351 days, need to be select TRUE.

I have implemented the below code:

```
DECLARE @Dob DATE
    ,@Subjectage DATE

SELECT @Subjectage = DATEADD(DAY, 351, DATEADD(YEAR, 16, @Dob))

IF @Subjectage <= GETDATE()
    SELECT 'TRUE'
```

Is this fine or need any changes for better?

Comment: Your implementation looks fine to me.  Are you having trouble with it?

Comment: No @Tim Friesen, it is working fine. But just to know is there any other smartway to implement this requirement